# Describe a partition of $\mathbb{N}$ that divides $\mathbb{N}$ into $\aleph_0$ countably infinite subsets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Does anyone have any hints on how to describe the following partition?

> Describe a partition of $\mathbb{N}$ that divides $\mathbb{N}$ into $\aleph_0$ countably infinite subsets.

Comment: Powers of $2$, powers of $3$,powers of $5$, ..., numbers that aren't powers of a prime.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

How many numbers are coprime to $2$?  How many numbers have exactly one factor of $2$?  How many numbers have exactly two factors of $2$?  $\dots$